# What is the point in discovering a material that is superconductor at very low temperatures?

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity

From my understanding what is really relevant is to obtain superconductivity
at high temperatures, as close as possible to standard conditions of pressure and temperature. So, what makes materials that show superconductivity at low temperature interesting?

Comment: Any new material offers the possibility of exploring the fundamentals of superconductivity more deeply, since you now have a wider range of experiment and theory to bring to the table. For example, if you had not yet observed a superconductor that contained $f$ electrons, one that did could prove quite interesting to the theory folks. New isn't always interesting in the end, but it might be.

Comment: You could say the same about fusion reactions. They would be really great if they happened at room temperature, so what use are the ones that happen at 100 million degrees? Nevertheless, we found some rather scary uses for those.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to imply that "low temperatures" are somehow unattainable. This is far from the case. Although it is quite an engineering challenge, maintaining temperatures of a few kelvin on an industrial scale is quite possible. Indeed this is what is done with all the bending magnets on the LHC at CERN.

Of course, if you happen to know of any material that becomes superconducting at a much higher temperature, accelerator designers would be happy to hear from you.

Comment: Your answer inspired my interest in knowing how expensive it is to work at low temperatures. I researched a bit and I found [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-cost-difference-between-low-and-high-temperature-superconductors).